# Can't update to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, and upgrade has failed due to connection problem. After fixing this problem and restarting my laptop, I couldn't update Ubuntu. Software Updater doesn't even start, Software Center starts but doesn't shows any software. I guess some of system files got broken. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading using this `sudo do-release-upgrade`